# BAMT Lan - Qualcomm Atheros AR8171

Tags: network, bamt

I got the the new MB http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H87M/?cat=Specifications which comes with **Qualcomm Atheros AR8171 Lan**, and unfortunately BAMT 1.2 does not have a driver for it included.

Does exists the way to install the missing driver, does the driver exists at all? I'm totally new to Linux and don't know even how to open command line in BAMT.

I use USB boot image from: https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=2924.0

If there no option to install the driver, can I use USB to LAN adapter without additional headaches, or I will need to install the driver to?

Comment: Having same problem, internet is empty from solutions

Comment: sorry i meant to comment.. now how do i erase it

Comment: At the end I ended up, by buying the USB to Ethernet adapter that has Linux support in specifications, and it just works :)  http://www.alibaba.com/lan-adapter-jp208b-manufacturers.html

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=105858#p506223

worked beautifully for me..